# Tracking the progress of a recursive method

Tags: data-structures, recursion, tree

I'm writing an application that makes use of a tree structure, so of course I have some recursive methods that will iterate down every node of the tree and do something. The problem is sometimes these take a while, and I'd rather show a progress bar of some sort to the user rather then the program stop responding for a period of time.

If I'm iterating through a flat list I know how many items are in the list to begin with so it's easy to keep track of what number the loop is at and update a progress bar accordingly.

But with a recursive method iterating a tree structure I don't necessarily know how many nodes the tree has at the beginning. Should I first recursively read through the tree and just count all the nodes before running the actual recursive method that does whatever I want to do? Or maybe just keep track of a running total as nodes are added or removed from the tree? Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach to this problem is to show a progress bar that is changing, but not updating an actual percentage.  For example, the little loading icon in Firefox is a circle-thing that is just spinning -- you know it's doing *something*, but you don't know how long it's going to take.  Maybe just do that and add a message that "this might take a moment depending on how much data there is..."

Comment: so obvious that I had to read this to think about it (: thx you saved me a few hours of headache that would probably have led me to that conclusion

Answer (score 3):

Stuck with the same problem, and I don't think you can give the user an accurate % elapsed if you don't know off the bat how many items there are to process. Instead, a textual status message could help.

Assuming you're able to tell how many objects you have at each level of your tree (which should be possible as it's a simple count), your message would show something like this when it's working on the first object and there are 50 objects at level 1:

> Processing: Level1 - 1/50

As soon as it is called recursively, and starts looking at level 2 for the current level 1 object, the message expands to add the second level status:

> Processing: Level1 - 1/50, Level2 - 1/25

As you continue looping through the objects on a given level, the section of the output message belonging to that level would be increased. So for the second object on level 2, you'd get:

> Processing: Level1 - 1/50, Level2 - 2/25

Once you're done with level two for current level 1 object, you remove the last section of the messsage and pop back to the calling level, and move on to the second object at that level:

> Processing: Level1 - 2/50

You continue adding and removing message sections as you go up and down the tree, all the while seeing that the section for level 1 is surely but slowly going up. It does not give an exact number of how much is left to go, but certainly gives the user a general idea.

If your tree is very deep, this message might get very long. There might be a cleaner way to do this.

Also, I would not just edit a message all the time. I would keep a singleton (in case the progress indication is being updated by several threads) with an internal list of levels and their statuses, and just ToString() it in order to keep things clean.

Finally, it would probably be neat to have some sort of tree progress indicator, where the sub branches are added and removed as per the above concept. Would certainly look more presentable than the messages.

Answer (score 2):

If the cost of tree traversal is low compared to the cost of the actual operation, then it is worth pre-computing progress data.

## The simplest way

As you described, counting all nodes, then keeping track of how many nodes have been completed as the operation is being applied.

Good enough for 99% of the cases. The caveat is  that if the operation is doing some pruning (jumping over unecessary nodes, etc.) then the node count is not an accurate depiction of progress as the jumped nodes do not contribute to the tally. So the bar might jump from 60% to 100% upon completion.
In the example below, the process jumps nodes below B

```
     A
    / \
   /   \
 (B)    F
 /|\   /|\
C D E G H I
```

The progress bar will indicate:

```
[Node] [True Progress] [Displayed]
A           10%           10%
 B          20%           20%
 F          60%           30%
  G         70%           40%
  H         80%           50%
  I         90%           60%
  -        100%          100%
```

## A more precise way using landmarks

You can place landmarks during the initial setup. Keep track of the first 200 items in a List. When you hit 200, let go of every other object on the list (to get back to 100 items). Now keep track of every other node encountered. When you hit 400 total nodes encountered, the list will have grown back to 200 object. You again let go of every other, but from this point on keep track of 1 in 4 objects, etc.

This way the landmark list oscillates between 100/200 nodes. When the tree is fully parsed, you may have ~120 objects on the list, evenly spread around the tree. Now you can start the operation. When encountering a node, check if it is the list. If it is, you can jump-start the progress bar to this element's position (if element is #84, then progress is at 84 / 120 = 70%

Some nodes may be skipped by the operation, but the progress should eventually encounter some landmarks, so the progress will jump back to an appropriate progress ratio.

All numbers are tweakable, so the landmark list size can be increased for better precision / reactivity.

Using the same example, with a list of 5 landmarks

```
              Node Landmarks Steps Comments
              A    [A----]   1     -
              B    [AB---]   1     -
     A        C    [ABC--]   1     -
    / \       D    [ABCD-]   1     -
   /   \      E    [ABCDE]   1     -
 (B)    F     F    [BDF--]   2     Cleanup of A&C&E
 /|\   /|\    G    [BDF--]   2     G is skipped
C D E G H I   H    [BDFH-]   2     -
              I    [BDFH-]   2     Done
```

We get a list of 5 landmarks, each representing 20%

Now while performing the operation (which skips over B entirely) the progress bar will indicate:

```
[Node] [True Progress] [Displayed]
A           10%            0%
 B          20%           20%
 F          60%           60%
  G         70%           60%
  H         80%           80%
  I         90%           80%
  -        100%          100%
```

## Improvement

It is possible to keep track of the lowest common ancestor (LCA) of two consecutive landmarks.
If the operation exits an LCA, it can infer its progress to have jumped the next landmark, thus giving some progress info even though landmark #85 was skipped.
The behaviour changes between entering and exiting a node: you register entering a landmark, and exiting a LCA

```
              Node Landmarks  LCA   Steps Comments
              A    [A----]   [----] 1     -
              B    [AB---]   [A---] 1     A is LCA of A&B
     A        C    [ABC--]   [AB--] 1     B is LCA of B&C
    / \       D    [ABCD-]   [ABB-] 1     B is LCA of C&D
   /   \      E    [ABCDE]   [ABBB] 1     B is LCA of D&E
 (B)    F     F    [BDF--]   [BA--] 2     Cleanup, recompute LCAs
 /|\   /|\    G    [BDF--]   [BA--] 2     Skipped
C D E G H I   H    [BDFH-]   [BAF-] 2     F is LCA of F&H
              I    [BDFHI]   [BAFF] 2     Should be skipped, is Registered as last node of the tree (F is LCA of H&I)
```

Now while performing the operation (which skips over B entirely) the progress bar will indicate:

```
  [Node] [True Progress] [Displayed] [Tracked ] [Tracked] [Comments]
                                     [Landmark] [  LCA  ]
->A           10%            0%        B          -        Tracking landmark B...
   ->B        20%           20%        D          B        Found Tracked Landmark B, Now tracking D (LCA of D,B is B)
    (B)       20%           20%        D          B        (Process skips Nodes C/D/E)
   <-B        60%           40%        F          A        Exiting LCA B, must have jumped over Landmark D, now tracking F
  A           60%           40%        F          A        -
   ->F        60%           60%        H          F        Entering Landmark F, now tracking H (LCA of F,H is F)
      ->G     70%           60%        H          F        -
      ->H     80%           80%        I          F        Found Tracked Landmark H, now tracking I (LCA if H, I is F)
      ->I     90%          100%                            Found Tracked Landmark I (last item), operation should be complete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do several things. You could adjust the data structure such that each node stores the size of the tree rooted at that node. Other than that:

- If the trees are generally big, then a separate run just to determine the tree size may not be such a good idea in terms of performance (esp. if the tree doesn't completely fit in the cache).
- If the trees are generally quite balanced, then after processing the *k*th subtree of a total of *n* subtrees, you have traversed approximately *k/n*100* percent of the nodes. You can use this knowledge as a measure of progress.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a status label that shows where you are at by some descriptor that would make sense to the useras the loop is being executed...

For example, if I were looping through an org chart, I'd know that my end users are familiar with most of the people on the org chart, so I would use the people's names.  As an example, if I report to Bob, who reports to Joe, who reports to Sue, when my record was being processed, the label would say something like..

```
Currently processing Sue\Joe\Bob\David
```

So you update the status label's text on each node.  Just be sure that you call Application.DoEvents() after changing the label's text so that the screen updates. If you really want to display how far along you are, a progress bar would be better, but this is an option that's worked for me in similar situations.  It gives some feedback as to what's happening, and the user experience is what really counts.

One caveat, however, is that updating the label text and calling Application.DoEvents() actually slows down processing, **but** it pays off usually because the users can see what's happening and know that the program isn't just "froze".

Answer (score 1):

I think adding an 'Items processed' count is often preferable to just having the back-and-forth progress bar that's basically a glorified hourglass.

Preferably, as the OP suggested, making your tree container do the necessary book keeping as items are added or deleted is a good option for reporting percentage of progress (potentially use a wrapper class to do this, especially if you want to store information related to branches that might be pruned when processing the tree in a way specific to your needs).

If that's not an option then below is an algorithm I've used that works well for reasonably evenly distributed trees (but fairly badly otherwise!).

ProcessTree would initially be called as ProcessTree(tree, 0, 0, 100). For cleaner code the itemsProcessed and percentDone parameters could be moved to member variables. The child collection bit can be omitted if your tree allows you to get a child count without fetching the items:

```
Sub ProcessTree(node As Tree, ByRef itemsProcessed As Long, ByRef percentDone As Double, percentThisItem As Double)
    Dim oChild As Tree
    Dim oChildCollection As Collection
    Dim percentPerChild As Double
    
    ProcessNode(node)
    itemsProcessed = itemsProcessed + 1
    ReportProgress(itemsProcessed, percentDone)
    
    Set oChildCollection = New Collection
    For Each oChild In node.Children
        oChildCollection.Add oChild
    Next

    If oChildCollection.count > 0 Then
        percentPerChild = percentThisItem / oChildCollection.count
        For Each oChild In oChildCollection
            ProcessTree oChild, itemsProcessed, percentPerChild, percentDone
        Next
    Else
        percentDone = percentDone + percentThisItem
        ReportProgress(itemsProcessed, percentDone)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A good progressbar would be based on the number of nodes in total (by doing a recursive count). An annoying but perhaps more efficient progressbar wouldbe the one that increases the MaxValue with every step of the recursion (making your progress steps tinier as you go). These methods could be combined by making a rough estimate before you start your method and update it as you go.

A Microsoft approach I guess would be to use the running-from-start-to-end-in-a-loop progressbar.

Comment: Interesting approach (increasing max value as we go along), but it would defeat the whole purpose of the progress bar because the user would never really know how much is left to do.

Comment: @DavidCatriel, it wouldn't defeat the purpose if you don't start with a MaxValue of 1. You could say: the MaxValue will be at least 30, so we set it to 30, if it turns out to be 33 we could increase it during the recursion. The user would have a sense of progress.